# How can I delete the cache of a particular function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, caching

I have a stored procedure named `STOREDPROC` which calls a table-valued function `TABLEFUNCTION`.

I know that I can delete the cache of stored procedure by executing it with the `WITH RECOMPILE` option. Will this also delete the cache for the function being called inside the procedure? If not, then is there a way to delete the cache of a given function in the SQL Server?

Comment: Use DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS to test queries with a cold buffer cache without shutting down and restarting the server. DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS serves to empty the data cache.

Comment: @DhruvinSukhadiya I read about `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`and found out that even though it clears the buffer pool, it is mainly used for performance testing, which is not my aim here.

Is there a better way?

Comment: @DhruvinSukhadiya Also, the problem with this command is that I do not have the permission to run this command. I think this command can only be run by the database admins, and I am not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article describe in detail how to get the cached plan for a function:

http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options

With this information, it should be relatively easy for you to determine if the use of the WITH RECOMPILE option is capable of clearing the cache of any embedded function. You should also check the use of `Option(Recompile)`.

You should also check the article http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2801413/en-us

BTW, for clearing the whole plan cache, you need to execute the command DBCC FREEPROCCACHE.

Comment: I'm unable to add the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint in a subquery. It is giving an incorrect syntax error. As the function that I'm calling from my stored procedure is an inline function, I'll use the `WITH RECOMPILE` hint in the stored procedure. Although, I would have liked to use the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint as I don't want to recompile all the queries in the stored procedure. I just want to recompile the query inside the function. But,sadly SQL server doesn't allow  to put `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint after the concerned query in the function.

Comment: You cannot just recompile a subquery or an inline function.  Both are integral part of the whole query; which is considered as a single unit by the compiler.  As for the OPTION(RECOMPILE); it's not just that it doesn't recompile all the queries of the stored procedure; it's also because it will often gives a better query plan than the option WITH(RECOMPILE).  In fact, even if you want to recompile all the queries in a SP, using OPTION(RECOMPILE) on each one will give you a better performance than the option WITH(RECOMPILE); if you don't take into account the required time for compiling.

Comment: However, because the process of recompiling a query or a SP take time; using any of these options is not necessarily the best option for you.  The real problem with compilation is usually with the "parameters sniffing" process of SQL-Server and they are other options than recompiling everytime that you can often use instead.

The reference in my answer give you all the detail about these other options.